# C#. Компилятор ругается, не может использовать лямбда выражение, т.к. не может определить тип аргумента. Как обойти?

Tags: c#, списки, лямбда-выражение

От одного и того же класса наследуются несколько других с дополнительными свойствами. Хочу написать универсальную функцию, которая бы работала со списками объектов этих новых классов, т.е. на вход список и параметр, а на выходе элемент списка. 
Вот упрощенный код того, что примерное хочу реализовать (функция FindByName):

```
class Animal
{
    public string Name;
}

class Dog:Animal
{
    //some other properties and methods
}

class Cat:Animal
{
    //some other properties and methods
}

class Program
{
    static dynamic FindByName(dynamic list, string name)
    {
        return list.Find(x => x.Name == name);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Dog> dogs = GetListOfDogs();
        //List<Cat> cats = GetListOfCats();

        Dog DogTuzik = FindByName(dogs, "Tuzik");
        //Cat Murka = FindByName(cats, "Murka");
    }

    static List<Dog> GetListOfDogs()
    {
        List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();
        dogs.Add(new Dog{Name="Tuzik"});
        dogs.Add(new Dog{Name="Sharik"});
        return dogs;
    }
}
```

Компилятор, естественно, ругается:

"*Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.*"

На самом деле FindByName гораздо объёмнее, чем в примере, поэтому и хочу убрать его в отдельную процедуру, чтобы сделать код более читаемым.

Поэтому вопрос, как сделать это правильно и может быть более изящно?

Comment: а почему в параметрах dynamic, а не List? и возвращается тоже dynamic. Можно возвращать Animal

Comment: в параметрах пробовал ставить List<dynamic>, но все равно компилятор ругается, а возвращает dynamic, потому что могут быть разные типы, в зависимости от того, что придет в списке в аргументе, а нужен именно тот класс, который приходит, а не родительский

Comment: если ставить List<dynamic> в аргументе, компилятор ругается, что невозможность преобразовать List<Dog> в List<dynamic>

Comment: `T FindByName<T>(List<T> list, string name) where T:Animal`

Comment: PetSerAl, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще это решается примерно так:

```
static T FindByName<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string name) where T : Animal
{
    return list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
}
```

Зы. Использовать `dynamic` в C# очень редко требуется, в основном при взаимодействии с какими-то внешними динамически типизированными языками/средами

Comment: спасибо за ответ, помог!
насчет Find, вроде стандартный метод списка: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Advarus, хм, точно, я по привычке использовал `IEnumerable<T>`...

Comment: @Advarus, ответ поправил, я вам рекомендую использовать всё же `IEnumerable<T>`, т.к. коллекции может быть удобно использовать отличные от `List<T>`. Да и вообще, например, может в Linq задействуете, а с `List` придется материализовать тогда результат запроса, что может быть не хорошо. Например: `FindByName(dogs.Where(d => d.Age < 5), "Tuzik");`

Comment: спасибо, Андрей!

Answer (score 0):

Можно оставить и `dynamic` но немного переделать метод в такой:

```
static dynamic FindByName<T>(dynamic list, string name) where T : Animal
{
    return list is List<T> animals ? animals.Find(x => x.Name == name) : null;
}
```

Comment: В чем смысл иметь `dynamic`, если в итоге мы приводим его к конкретному типу? Причем `T` компилятор самостоятельно вывести не сможет и его всегда нужно будет указывать вручную. Этот совет вреден и приведет только к увеличению трудоемкости и возможным ошибкам во время исполнения